# IOS: Create relationship between two objects when using CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I have two entities in core data, books and authors.  Authors can have more than one book but books can only have one author.

So in the authors entity, I have 'to many' relationship with books. And in the books entity, I have a 'to one' relationship with author.  Core Data does not seem to have the option to give you a many to one relationship per se.  If this is the issue, would appreciate someone letting me know.

In the NSManaged objects for each relationship, I have

in books:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Authors *author;
```

and in authors

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *book;
```

Again, I think this is correct so please tell me if this is wrong

When the user creates a new book object, I let them associate it with an author. This author is saved in a property called `_selectedAuthor`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Authors *selectedAuthor;
```

After the book object is saved as book, the final task is to associate it with the selectedauthor object.  I am trying to do this as follows:

```
_selectedAuthor.book = book;
```

However, this throws exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "book"; desired type = NSSet; given type = Books; value = <Books: 0x13615a9c0> (entity: Book; id: 0xd000000018600000 <x-coredata://34410921-1612-4B04-BC39-07F8ABD02E8C/Dare/p1560> ; data: {
    bid = 23;
   name = Exodus;
    activity = nil;
}).'
```

When I turn it around and try to do

```
book.author=_selectedAuthor;
```

It compiler gives error `'Property author not found on object of type NSManagedObject'` although the books class does have a author property for what it is worth.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this error

Comment: Hi. `_selectedAuthor.book = book;` - it's wrong. It should be as `_selectedAuthor.book = [NSSet setWithObject:book];`

Comment: This would crash for sure. The problem is with this line `_selectedAuthor.book = book;`. The relationship of an `Author` to the `Book` is once to many. In your `Authors` entity you have an `NSSet` of `Books`. So you need to assign a set to this property.

Comment: Which language are you using? And are you using a third party library like `MagicalRecords` or doing everything on your own?

Comment: Mozilla, your suggestion did trick.  Thx!  Sorry I don't have rep to up vote your comment.

Comment: @Mozilla wouldn't it overwrite the previous record of books if there is any?

Comment: @Adeel My comment is just a fast hint. I'm understand if `author` already has another set of `books`, then from my example code will overwrite the whole set of books.